# PHP date change strtotime does not work well

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, date-formatting

Date doesn't change the format(YYYYMM -> YYYYY-MM) correctly.

I would like to get YYYYMM (int) changed YYYY-MM to use HTML month input

I implemented like this... but  $s_month always displays 2021-06 somehow

```
                {{$test->month }}//202005
@php
                $s_month= $test->month ? date('Y-m',strtotime($test-> month)):"";
@endphp
{{$s_month}} // it displays 2021-06
<input name="s_month" type="month" value="{{$s_month?? ''}}"></input>
```

Comment: Use `DateTime` or `Carbon` classes. `strtotime` is less reliable because it can only guess the format it received, while the classes have an explicit method to create a date object from a specific format.

Comment: works fine with input of `2020-05` but not with `202005` so I change the question so it makes sence

Comment: Simple solution, concatenate an `01` to the `YYYYMM` to make a valid full date and then it will work So `date('Y-m',strtotime($test-> month . '01'))`

Answer (score 2):

[Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) solution:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
$s_month= $test->month ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Ym', $test->month)->format('Y-m') : "";
```

native [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime) solution:

```
$s_month= $test->month ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $test->month)->format('Y-m') : "";
```

Comment: Not really very helpful, quite possibly the OP, or future visitors will not know Carbon. Therefore you would have to tell them how to install it if they want to use it. Its not vanilla PHP where the DATETIME class is

Comment: They don't need to install it since Laravel only has it installed. I wouldn't have used it otherwiese.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added a native DateTime solution

Comment: Sure. Not everyone that finds this Q&A will be using Blade either. We're not asking the thread owner to rephrase their question either.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @shaedrich on this one - the tags do make it clear that this is a Laravel question, however I do agree that a plain language solution should always also be provided when possible.

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` (rightfully) isn't smart enough to parse a string without a delimiter because the value could be anything, milliseconds, nanoseconds, an epoch, etc. One option would be to add a delimiter:

```php
$originalDate = '202005';
$separateDate = substr($originalDate, 0, 4) . '-' . substr($originalDate, 4, 6); // 2020-05
```

At this point you'd have your raw date manually stripped out, but for completeness sake and ensuring we've accomplished our goal, we can use this string in our date objects.

```php
$intendedDate = date('Y-m', strtotime($separateDate)); // 2020-05
```

Alternatively, as [mentioned by @shaedrich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67800970/2634190), [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) is very useful and can accomplish this much more elegantly.